# @reboot cron directive doesn't work on Solaris? What do I use instead?

Tags: cron, solaris

I just tried to use `contab -e` on a Solaris server to add this line:

```
@reboot /root/reboot.sh
```

The script starts up the web application.  But the trouble is that this syntax is rejected.

```
# crontab -e
@reboot /root/reboot.sh
crontab: error on previous line; unexpected character found in line.
crontab: errors detected in input, no crontab file generated.
```

And I'm guessing because this is Solaris? What cron syntax do I use instead?

Comment: What did the `man` page say on that system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@reboot` and similar `@` time values are a feature of Vixie cron. Solaris uses the System V version of cron. ([Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron))

Essentially you can't do what you want via the scheduler so will either need a cron job that runs regularly to check if your service is running, or otherwise write an `init` script (or transient SMF service for Solaris 10).

Comment: How does an `init` script work then?

Comment: That's really beyond the scope of this question or even this site. This site is geared towards professional systems administrators and writing an init script is fairly basic stuff. I suggest you search for examples and ask on [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com) if you need further help.